# Flex GestureZoom not working properly specific area

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I tried zoom in and out functionality for android mobile ,by using 
transformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM  but it does not zooming  properly ,because it's always zoom center point only not exact between two fingers within content (specific area).

I tried below 3 functions sample for zoom in and out

```
        1.  private function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void/* not working properly  */
        {
            swfLoader.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
            swfLoader.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
        }
        2. private function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void/* not working properly  */
        {
            swfLoader.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2;
            swfLoader.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2;
        }3. private function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
        {
            // scale the view
            swfLoader.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
            swfLoader.scaleY *= e.scaleY;

            var bounds2:Rectangle = swfLoader.content.getBounds(swfLoader.stage);
            var dx:Number = bounds2.x - bounds1.x;
            var dy:Number = bounds2.y - bounds1.y;
            var dw:Number = bounds2.width - bounds1.width;
            var dh:Number = bounds2.height - bounds1.height;

            // move the view to keep it centered while zooming
            swfLoader.x -= dx + dw/2;
            swfLoader.y -= dy + dh/2; 

        }<s:BorderContainer id="contentPanel" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#cccccc" >
    <s:Scroller id="scroller" width="100%" height="100%"   >
                <s:VGroup id="swfloadergroup" width="100%" height="100%"  horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"  >

                <s:SWFLoader id="swfLoader" smoothBitmapContent="true"  autoLoad="true" doubleClickEnabled="true"
                             maintainAspectRatio="true" gestureZoom="onZoom(event)" scaleContent="true" loadForCompatibility="true"  />

                <s:SWFLoader id="preLLoader" autoLoad="true"  width="30%" height="30%"
                             source="@Embed('assets/loading.swf')"
                             maintainAspectRatio="true" scaleContent="true "/>
                </s:VGroup> 

    </s:Scroller>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

So what did wrong in my code . how can i zoom exact content(specific area) between two fingers . if anybody know then Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransformGestureEvent has `localX` and `localY` properties which contain coorinates of the center between two fingers.

Though you can't zoom an object from a non-center point without moving it so only by zooming gestures you can move even a 'stationary' one. To make the gesture look natural first you need to move your sprite by the difference between positions and then zoom it from specific point.

You will need `oldLocalX` and `oldLocalY` to keep old coordinates. Set these vars to current localX/localY when `gesture.phase == GesturePhase.BEGIN`. After that move your sprite by new delta.

To zoom an object from a specific point do the following:

```
var matrix:Matrix = this.transform.matrix;
matrix.translate(-event.localX, -event.localY);
matrix.scale(event.scaleX, event.scaleY);
matrix.translate(event.localX, event.localY);
this.transform.matrix = matrix;
```

Comment: Still not working properly .I tried keep localx and oldlocaly , when gesture phase end . and when gesture begin set these vars to current localx/y but working any idea ... if(event.phase == GesturePhase.END)  {
     trace('End'+oldlocalY);
     
     oldlocalX = event.localX;
     oldlocalY = event.localY;
     
    }

Answer (score 0):

I got it . when i tried for zoom specific area ,I used below code for this . It's working but not scrolling .

```
 Mtransform = swfLoader.content.transform.matrix; 
            Mtransform.translate( -originX, -originY );
            Mtransform.scale( scale, scale );
            Mtransform.translate( originX, originY );
            swfLoader.content.transform.matrix = Mtransform;
```